# Getting "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" with `socket.socket()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

When I execute this code I get the following error:

```
import socket
s=socket.socket()
s.connect(("data.pr4e.org",80))
cmd='GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
s.send(cmd)
while True:
    data=s.recv(512)
    if (len(data)<1):
            break
    print(data.decode())
s.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/home/arnav/WorkSpace/Python/Coursera/AccessWebData/socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    s=socket.socket()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

When this code is entered on the terminal, it works just fine.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @nicolallias He is not missing `from socket import socket` since he is doing `s=socket.socket()` instead of `s=socket()`. Also i wouldnt consider this a duplicate since he added much more context than the original question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main issue is your file name is also `socket.py` and the first line of your code is also `import socket`. 
So basically python code is trying to import itself and hence it is failing.

Please rename the file to `socket_use_case.py` and it would solve your problem